# Detect a mail link and when pressed, mail the address in app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email

How can I detect when a mailto link is pressed in a `UIWebView`, and when it is pressed, open a window in the app to send the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the webview to recognize the links as

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

here is a link which will be of help I guess...

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21630-open-email-editor-href-link-uiwebview.html

Comment: but surely isn't this for all links, not just mail ones?

Comment: I have found something on iphoneDevSdk check if this helps ...I guess it will work only for email rather than everything.... http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21630-open-email-editor-href-link-uiwebview.html  I have also edited my answer above, coz i think this is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

implement below method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView1 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    NSURL *requestURL = [request URL];  
    NSString *str_url = [requestURL absoluteString];
    if([str_url isEqualToString:@"about:blank"]){
        return YES;
    } else {
        //you can write  mailComposeController methods over here
    }
}
```

Comment: but surely isn't this for all links, not just mail ones?